# Why CRUD razor pages in ASP.net CORE does not work out-of-box after Scaffolding with Database-first approch?

Tags: .net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

in VS 2019 i have created an web-app like this:
[image]

After that i have:

1. Created a database, and added it in VS2019 "SQL server explorer" (so connection is fine)
2. Then Scaffolded according to the command in the lasted post here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19986, and i get my "class/model" as a result of this.
3. Then I add my CRUD pages like demonstrated in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2u1VY28Drs
   And that is ok, since the CRUD pages are created (Exists in solution explorer).
   [image]

Now when i start the app, and manouver to the new CRUD pages as shown i the last video link, it does not work out of the box, the page does not exist: *No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44335/V2/index*. I dont understand why, but suspect it has something to do with routing.

Or, what could be the problem here?
tnx

**Updated 19.10**

I create a MCV app, and follow the steps 1&2 above, then i follwo this guide  at the "Add model" step: **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/?view=aspnetcore-3.1 ** and [image]

then add this: *using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore*; in my startup file. I do not add *using MvcMovie.Data;*
And it still do not work, the documentation is **lacking** to be mild on the database first approach. What do i NEED to do from the step: "Add a Model" in the MVC guide? anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or, what could be the problem here?

The key of this issue is that the project in this video is in **`asp.net core razor page`** rather than `asp.net core mvc`.

When you create the project, in **Create a new ASP.NET Core web application** box ,you should choose the template of **Web Application**, you can have a look for [official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-the-movie-model):

[image]

Then you can follow the video operation to create the crud pages.

If it is in the `asp.net core mvc` project, you need to create New scaffolded Item in the `Controller` folder and should select `MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework` template, you can have a look for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-movie-pages).

Comment: Ok, i see. I think i mixed the two different approaches. I will try the MVC approach first. Thanks

Comment: hm, yeah. But it is not straightforward since i have Database first approche. Following the MVC guide, i get problems adding a model. I scaffold it from the PM command line, but that does not generate the "DATA" folder or using that namespace as described in the guide. And after the model is generated, and i want to Scaffold MVC views + controller I get a "Code generator"-error.....

Comment: @otk, actually, when you excute scaffold commad to the `DATA` folder, you should create an empty DATA folder in your project first, then use this command: `Scaffold-DbContext "connectionstring..." Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir DATA`, have a reference for this document:https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx, after all tables covnert into classes in DATA folder, you just need to scaffold  in controller , which will generate controller code and views code.

Comment: @otk, did my answer help you solve the issue? If so, please accept it as the answer , or you can tell me what your current issue.

Comment: I belive your answer points in the right direction, that one cant mix the two different approaches. And following the separate guides you refer will probably solve the case. I ended up following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database
dropping the .net Core... as it seems easier(safer?) for me. And it runs out-of-the-box :)